# Understanding of the EFLAGS register in x86, going from 1 to 0 to -1 and back

Tags: assembly, x86, flags, eflags

My book and most sources show that when the carry flag is changed from 0 to 1, but i dont understand why the EFL register changes values in much bigger increments as show below: i put comments showing the change to the register value. like when moving from 0 to 1 to back to 0 to -1.

```
mov eax , 0FFFFFFFFh
add eax , 1         ;flag from A12 to 257
inc eax             ; flag to 203
neg eax             ; flag to 297
inc eax             ; flag to 257
dec eax             ; flag to 297

inc eax             ; flag to 257
dec eax             ; flag to 297

mov ebx , 0         ;flag doesnt move
sub ebx , 1         ;flag doesnt move

inc ebx             ; flag move to 257
dec ebx             ; flag move to 297


dec eax             ; flag to 283

mov ebx , 0         ;flag doesnt move
sub ebx , 1         ;flag to 297

mov eax , 00FFFFFFFh    ;flag doesnt move
add eax , 1         ;flag to 216

mov ebx , 0Fh           ;flag doesnt move
sub ebx , 1         ;flag to 202
```

Comment: It really doesn’t make sense to look at the flags register in decimal. It is a collection of bits, so you should look at it in binary (or octal or hex, which are equivalent, if you can visualize the bits in your head).

Comment: Look up the bit position of each flag in the flags register and note each flag that changes for each instruction, and I think it will become clear to you.

Comment: there's no `EFL` register in x86

Comment: @phuclv it’s not uncommon to abbreviate EFLAGS as EFL.

Comment: `EFLAGS` contains a set of flags and `CF` is only one of them. Arithmetic instructions update more than one flags according to the result (like `ZF`, `SF`) and the change (like `CF` and `OF`). So you need to look at individual bits to understand each flag.The funny thing about your example is that `INC` and `DEC` actually don't update `CF`.

Answer (score 1):

As @prl mentioned in the comments, it doesn't make sense to look at the flags as single value. Bits in the flags register are individual flags, and aside from IOPL should be viewed as distinct entities.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) entry has explanation and references that serve as good starting point to figure out exactly how they work.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's an `EFL` register in x86.

Comment: There isn't, but [as prl commented on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356973/understanding-of-the-efl-register-in-x86-going-from-1-to-0-to-1-and-back#comment106773133_60356973), some people abbreviate EFLAGS to EFL, and that's pretty clearly the case here.  The mention of the Carry Flag, and the numeric values changing on FLAGS-setting instructions but not on `mov`, makes it pretty certain.  I wouldn't be surprised if the querent had been using a debugger whose UI used EFL for that.

Comment: @PeterCordes: lDebug is [among the debuggers](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/ldebug.htm#helpr) that recognise `efl` and `fl` as register names. Looking [at the source](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/fddebug/file/1c29b3f32729/DEBUG.ASM#l611) of the latest FreeDOS Debug also shows it recognises `fl` and `efl` too. Both also support the `f` pseudoregister, only for `r f` commands, which allow modifying individual flag states (eg `r f CY` = set carry flag).